# Can't create a new table with the keyword CONSTRAINT

Tags: mysql, constraints, primary-key, create-table

I'm a beginner at mysql on linux (ubuntu 22.4), while checking a document with the basics i came across an example of how to create a primary key, but with the constraint keyword:

CREATE TABLE
Empleados (
IdEmpleado INTEGER CONSTRAINT IndicePrimario PRIMARY,
Nombre TEXT,
Apellidos TEXT,
FechaNacimiento DATETIME
)

But when i type the command, i get this error.

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT indice PRIMARY KEY)' at line 1

I tried some modifications such as "int" instead of integer, or "primary key" instead of just primary, adding "not null" and so on, but is still the same error.
I already tried to search why is it wrong, but can't figure it out. If anyone could help, id appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding constraint separately as shown below,

```
CREATE TABLE Empleados (
    IdEmpleado int NOT NULL,
    Nombre varchar(255),
    Apellidos varchar(255),
    FechaNacimiento datetime,
    CONSTRAINT IndicePrimario PRIMARY KEY (IdEmpleado)
);
```

Comment: I get "no database selected"

Comment: Try switching to the database in which you want to create the table. FYI, `use <database-name>;` :)